# Sliding certain records to the end of a run of the same date

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting

I have three columns -

- `TheDate` - Obviously a date.
- `TheID` - A strictly increasing ID.
- `TheType` - A Record type.

I want these to sort by `TheID` in almost all cases except for just one record type. Records of the special record type must appear at the end of all records with the same date.

Example:

[image: Move record type 101 to the end of that date/time run]

I want the record type `101` to appear **after** all other records that have the same date. In all other cases `TheID` controls the order.

My attempt goes like:

```
ORDER BY 
TheDate, 
CASE WHEN TheType = 101 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
TheID
```

which *nearly* does what I want but is doing far more - i.e. it will reorder by `TheDate` which is not waht I want.

If the same date occurs later in the data I don't care - it's just when a sequence of records containing a type 101 (when sorted by `TheID`) all have the same date I want type `101` to be last.

Comment: Can it be assumed that when rows are ordered by `TheID`, the values of `TheDate` are non-decreasing, as in the example data?  If so, then it seems your existing `ORDER BY` clause must give you the desired order, leaving me uncertain what you mean by "not [what] I want".

Comment: @JohnBollinger - Would there be an easy solution if that was a fair assumption? If so, assume away. In general, the problem is *given a cluster of records of the same date (when sorted by `TheID`), move the 101's to the end*.

Comment: Yes. I updated my previous comment to clarify while you were responding to it.  If `TheDate` is non-decreasing with ascending `TheId`, then sorting by `TheDate` and then `TheId` should produce the same order as sorting by `TheId` alone, and sorting by `TheDate` then a special key, then `TheId`, as you're already doing, should produce the order you describe.  I'm trying to determine whether your problem is with the results or with the method.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - Experimenting - will get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is complicated. First you must find consecutive date records, so with

```
thedate     theid  thetype
2014-07-12   5001       59
2014-07-12   5002      101
2014-07-12   5003       88
2014-07-13   5004       10
2014-07-12   5005       60
```

you would identify 2014-07-12 as one occurrence for the first three records and another for the last record. The second record would have to get position #3 in your results, not #5.

You achieve this by giving consecutive records a group key by using first `LAG` to look into the previous record, thus creating a flag on group change, and then cumulating these flags.

```
select thedate, theid, thetype
from
(
  select 
    thedate, theid, thetype,
    sum(new_group) over (order by theid) as group_key
  from
  (
    select
      thedate, theid, thetype,
      case when lag(thedate) over (order by theid) = thedate then 0 else 1 as new_group
    from mytable
  ) marked
) grouped
order by 
  group_key,
  case when thetype = 101 then 1 else 0 end,
  theid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking the liberty granted in comments to assume that `TheDate` is non-decreasing with ascending `TheId`, if `r1.TheId < r2.TheId` then it must be the case that `r1.TheDate <= r2.TheDate` (that's the definition of non-decreasing).  In that case, ordering first by `TheDate` and then by `TheId` produces the same order as ordering by `TheId` alone.  Looking at it from the other direction, ordering by `TheId` automatically produces results clustered by `TheDate` and in order by date.

But what you're already doing differs from ordering by (`TheDate`, `TheId`) (which we already established is the same as ordering by just `TheId`) only by moving the special records to the end of each date cluster, which is exactly what you say you want.  Thus, you must be getting your results in the desired order; if you in fact have any problem then it must be that you are dissatisfied with the means by which you are doing so.  For instance, perhaps you are concerned with query performance.

If your existing ordering indeed produces the correct results, however, then I'm having trouble seeing an alternative that I would expect to deliver substantially better performance.  No doubt the ordering can be produced by  means that do not rely on `TheDate` to be non-decreasing, but I would expect all of those to be comparatively expensive to compute.

Answer (score 0):

If TheID cannot be null then just change the TheID to null as part of the order by where TheType is a special value:

```
order by TheDate, 
         case TheType
           when 101 then null
           else TheID
         end nulls last
```

Comment: That still adds a sort by `TheDate` a-priori which I *think* is not what I am looking for. I believe the primary sort should be by `TheID` and only the `101` records should be adjusted. Although I have to admit JohnBollinger's comments are making me think about that carefully.

Comment: It would help to know how the values are generated. If the ID is sequence generated on insert, and the timestamp is created on insert also, then they would correlate. any degree of non-correlation would be detectable with a query for an ID having a greater value than "current row" but an earlier timestamp.

Comment: The `TheDate` is a sort of session date generated at a remote site that groups a number of records into one session. These records are then transferred to a home database where they are stamped with a sequence `TheID`. The problem is that the transfer can re-order the records slightly (transfer is multi-threaded) so even though the `101` record is always generated last, sometimes it can race the previous record and get an earlier `TheID` than some of it's siblings. I have no control over this process so cannot fix it properly. I need to move the `101` to always be last of any session.

Comment: It sounds as if the reordering would occur within a set of records defined by a common timestamp, or is there any other column value that defines a set of siblings?

Comment: Sadly no other column seems to be of use here. If a session contains a 101 it must be at the end of the session and a session is defined by it's date.

Comment: If a session is defined by a unique date, and within that session the 101 must be last and the others are sorted by ID, then this logic would work for you. It all depends on the definition of the session really.

Comment: I am beginning to believe you are correct (and therefore so is @JohnBollinger) for my specific case. I will leave this open for a few days anyway just incase some magical method appears, meanwhile I must pick a *correct answer* between the two of you.